# In django, Is there any way to send the variable name in models.objects.fillter()

Tags: django-models

I have a register model.

models.py

```
class Register(models.Model):
    uname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    upassword = models.CharField(max_length==10)
```

I have to list down only particular query set of users which i have stored in the db.

I saved three datas in register model.
1. uname is 'abc'
2. uname is 'abs'
3. uname is 'abc'

I am trying to login with 'abc' uname

views.py

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_name = request.POST.get('user_name')   --> user_name is 'abc'
     pas = request.POST.get('password')

    #all_entries = models.Register.objects.all()
    #for x in all_entries.iterator():
    #print(x.uname)

       filtered_entry = models.Register.objects.filter(uname=form_name) -> form_name is variable name
```

when I try to print the filtered_entry it is showing an empty query set
but when i pass the value in uname like below I am getting the data in query set.

filtered_entry = models.Register.objects.filter(uname='abc')

I have an another option to filter it out which i have commented above but I have to send only the variable name to filter.

During registration process i am allowing duplicate users also.

Thanks

Comment: You did not add quotes in the request?

Comment: you mean the variable form_name?